# PNG support for python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, png, gis

I can't find any librarys for python 3.3 which add support for PNG images. What i need is to write polygons, lines and points to "tiles" of 254*254 images, which will be saved to the harddrive. Any sugestions or links to distributions of etc. PIL for python 3.3?

BTW i'm using Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pillow 2.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0) supports Python 3, including 3.3:

> **Note**: Pillow >= 2.0.0 supports Python versions: 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3; Pillow < 2.0.0 supports Python versions: 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7.

Pillow is a fork of PIL that adds (much) better packaging and patches and improvements to make PIL work on Python 3.

Windows installers and eggs are included.